# Instagram Graph API Webhook

Tags: instagram, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to set up a service for Instagram which is triggered by a new post of a subscribed user (want to setup a webhook for this). It will then put some comment underneath that new post.

But is it even possible to configure such a webhook? It looks like you can only subscribe to a users mention or story expiration. I'm not sure if this is possible or that i should user the previous Instagram API instead.

I'm clueless.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't advise using the old Instagram API as it will be fully deprecated next year. As you said, Instagram Graph API webhooks don't provide this functionality (yet)? One possible solution may be to periodically call [the media endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/) for an Instagram business account. This call includes the timestamp:

```
<INSTAGRAM_BUSINESS_ACCOUNT_ID>/media?fields=timestamp
```

Then, when you see a new post, you can act accordingly.

Comment: Since I want my service to work for non-business accounts, i chose to implement this on the old Instagram API for now. I know it will be deprecated and will watch closely to these new feature of the Instagram Graph API. 

The old Instagram API does not support webhooks at all, so it has to call the api every x time for a new post. 

Thank you for you're answer.